# How to hide rows of another worksheet by assigning a script in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two worksheet/sheet in a google sheet, namely "Company" and "Data". In the "Data" sheet I have a button "Hide Rows" which will hide certain rows on "Company" Sheet on click. For this I have written following AppScript.

```
function hideRows() {
  const ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Company');
  ss.hideRow(3);
}
```

But it is showing following error upon clicking the "Hide Rows" button:

```
Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.hideRow.
```

How to correct the code so that I can hide one or several rows of separate sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to `ss.hideRows(3)`

**TL;DR**

There are several ways to hide rows in a sheet, but each has a specific syntax.

**hideRow(row)** - [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowrow)

This is the method that you called but this hides a row *in a given range*. So if you wanted to use that method, you should have specified a range. For example:

`var range = sheet.getRange("A3")`
`sheet.hideRow(range)`

**hideRows(rowIndex)** - [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex)

This alternative hides the row at the given index. This is the method that you were trying to use and the code would be:

`ss.hideRows(3)`

**hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)** - [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex,-numrows)

There's also amethod if you want to hide multiple (contiguous) rows through a single command.